# Process files until every file is processed

Tags: python, pipeline

I've got the following situation: I have a lot of html files in the directory "path". My pipeline works on these html files and produces an xml output of the file to the directory "out". Using python, I call my pipeline like this:

```
datei = '../path/'+str(filename)
p = subprocess.Popen(["./process", "-d", "../data", "-t", "../temp", "-o", "../output", datei], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) # function call
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Now my question is: How would you upgrade the code s.t. it checks whether the filename which the server is working on is already in "out" or not? If it is already in "out", the next file in "path" can be picked. If the filename is not in "out", the computer should continuing working on this file.

Thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: Have a look at the pathlib module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) you can use it to easily see what files are in what directories.

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying this is the only way, but you can do it.

```
 while not os.path.exists("../path/"+filename):
      # perform some sort of operation
      # add some delay if needed.
```